# How to Filter All Internet Access on Android

Tags: android, networking, android-permissions, firewall

I would like to make an app that allows you to block certain internet sites on Android. For instance, you set what sites to block in my app, then when you try to access that site through chrome (or another browser on Android) you are denied access.

The [trend micro app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.trendmicro.tmmspersonal&hl=en) can do this, as can some others, however I cannot work out how. Possible ideas I have are as follows (although I am not an android dev, not sure on feasibility):

- Set up VPN / proxy that runs in-app, routing all device traffic through this. Seems like a lot of work to tunnel all traffic via your app.
- Set up a DNS proxy, however that only will filter at domain level (rather than URL level) and has some other issues
- Edit hosts table. Requires root access.

Is there any other way I missed? How do similar apps do this, and how would you go about it? It would be great if there was some way to hook in to network calls to accept / block / redirect traffic rather than having to tunnel all network data through my app. Thanks

Comment: in general it is not possible without user confirming he wants to do that. You could do it using VPN, but the user has to confirm he allows your app to establish VPN connection. You can setup a proxy, and it should work for WIFI, but there are problems to expect on different phone models. Also you should understand that your app could easily be treated as malware due to nobody knows for which purpose you are going to use the traffic you capture with it.

Comment: Agreed. It will be completely up front with the user, and all explained for them, but ultimately they will need to trust me. Currently not planning to widely distribute, just for me and a few friends, but may put it on the app store if it works well

Comment: then I'd say that VPN is best choice - it is totally transparent for the user - they know that it is used, and it captures all the traffic, including wifi, cellular, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the app "Netguard" in this case. Although per site traffic filtering requires a pro package, I think it's worth the shot. Netguard filters trafiic quite well and also has packet capture option by default.